# Lat/Long projection issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, csv

I have a CSV file with mainly UK data - postcodes that I have then referenced to there Latitude and Longitude. I have 5 rows that are outside the United Kingdom, so I have looked up the Latitude and longitude of these points and also added these to the dataset. 
[image: Sample Data]

I am trying to plot these points on a world map - the aim is to eventually create a webmap using qgis2web. I have got a shapefile I have downloaded from Eurostat:
1:10 Million    World   Point / Line / Polygon  Shapefile   2014    ETRS89
When I add my delimited text layer in QGIS using the latitude and longitude values the points are way off where they should be even when choosing ETRS89 as the coordinate system.
[image: Point Data]

The majority of the points should be sitting above London in the UK, but are actually off the coast of Africa!

I have tried using different coordinate systems and basemaps, but I cannot get any of them to line up. I know it is probably something really simple, but it is baffling me currently.

Comment: Did you set the polygon crs to ETRS89?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by polygon crs? Apologies, but I am a student so do not have extensive knowledge of QGIS.

Comment: Right click on the layer and choose set layer projection, then select ETRS89

Comment: Yes, sorry the layer is set to ETRS89 and when I imported the csv via delimited text layer I selected ETRS89 as its projection.

Comment: But your csv layer is in lat /lon which is epsg:4326

Comment: I have changed the layer for the polygon shape file to epsg:4326, but it seems to make no difference. The points are still way off.

Comment: But that layer is in ETRS89 so it should be set to that, the csv file is in epsg:4326 so it should be set to that. Then they will line up

Answer (score 8):

From the image you are most probably reversing longitude and latitude. When you use the Add Delimited text option be sure you are selecting the column "Lat" as the Y value, and "Lon" as the X value.